# "export 'createStackNavigator' was not found in '@react-navigation/native-stack'

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to navigate between two screens in react native and when I load my expo screen it shows up blank. There is also an error that states "export 'createStackNavigator' was not found in '@react-navigation/native-stack'". This is very strange since I was watching a tutorial and all it said I needed to do was declare the constant in react native.

My code for my app.js is:

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import {createStackNavigator} from "@react-navigation/native-stack";
import Home from "./screens/homescreen";
import SecondScreen from "./screens/secondscreen"

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <Stack.Screen name ="Home" component = {Home}/>
        <Stack.Screen name ="SecondScreen" component = {SecondScreen}/>
      </Stack.Navigator>

    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};




export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

The native stack creator has a different name than the original, according to the [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/native-stack-navigator/):

```js
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function MyStack() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Notifications" component={Notifications} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Settings" component={Settings} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Comment: So what do I need to fix?

Comment: `import {createStackNavigator} from "@react-navigation/native-stack";` becomes `import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';`. `
`const Stack = createStackNavigator();` becomes `const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();`

Answer (score 0):

As the error reports, such a property is not being exported in this dependency, that is, it does not exist there, or it is not declared as you try to import in your code

In these cases, make sure you have configured an extension that gives the code hint, and type the keywords of the property you want to call.